# ember-cli (2.4.3) not generating DS models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am very surprised not to get DS models upon generating ember-cli model

```
ember -v
ember-cli: 2.4.3
node: 5.10.1
os: darwin x64

ember g model rental
```

Then I get :

```
// app/models/rentals
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
export default Model.extend({
});
```

according to the ember guide , I should get :

```
// app/models/rentals
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
});
```

what could be wrong ? thanks for feedback

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the generated code :)

Ember Data has been made an addon, and part of that work was to tweak the public ES6 modules so everything doesn't hang off of the `DS` object. Now you can directly import the `Model` like in the first code sample you show.

I have opened an issue on the [Guides repository](https://github.com/emberjs/guides/issues/1373) to fix the Tutorial section of the guides.

Comment: It has since been updated! It will get deployed with Ember 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

The new generated code should look like the following,

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr' ;


export default Model.extend({
    title: attr('string'),
    owner: attr('string')
});
```

Comment: nice turnaround ember community https://github.com/emberjs/guides/commit/e58dd6123309cdda8c856681e8f0c7cff664b4bb#diff-e6942fb0645ba2043e474f25357f00d4L43